# Sessions in ASP.NET Core 1.0

Tags: session, asp.net-core

I am trying to use Session in my ASP.NET Core 1.0 (vNEXT) project. This is how my code looks like.

```
public class Startup
{
    // For more information on how to configure your application, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=398940
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        //-- Enabled MVC Pattern
        services.AddMvc();

        //-- Enable Session handling
        services.AddCachingServices();
        services.AddSessionServices();
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
        //-- User MVC
        app.UseMvc();

        //-- Use Session
        app.UseSession();
        app.UseInMemorySession();
    }
}
```

But now I am stuck. I don't know how to set or get data from the session in my controller or pages. I have tried the this.Context.Session. But it's not instanced, so an invalidexception is throw when i try to access that properties.

Anybody that has an code example on how to get this working.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**

Here is a screendump how the base.context.Session looks like in my controller.
[image]

And I don't have the SetString() and GetString(), only the Set() and TryGet()... methods...

This is how my project.json file looks like.

```
"version": "1.0.0-*",
"dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.IIS":  "1.0.0-beta3",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "6.0.0-beta3",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Session":  "1.0.0-beta3"

},
```

Comment: Add the session middleware *before* anything that needs it. Otherwise it won't be available at the right point in the request pipeline (the middleware is in essence run sequentially).

Comment: ohh... Thanks. I switch places in my startup.cs file, and put the UseMVC() last and now it works. Thanks!!!

Comment: I changed my comment to an answer if you want to accept it so others will see it more easily.

Comment: Here's a more detailed tutorial: http://benjii.me/2015/07/using-sessions-and-httpcontext-in-aspnet5-and-mvc6/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Changing my comment to an answer:

Add the session middleware before anything that needs it. Otherwise it won't be available at the right point in the request pipeline.

The middleware is in essence run sequentially - each middleware component that you add with `.UseXyz()` is run in order. So if MVC runs before Session, then MVC can't see the session acquisition from the Session middleware.

Answer (score 1):

Have you added the dependency to your `project.json` file?

```
"Microsoft.AspNet.Session": "1.0.0-beta3"
```

Once you have done that, you should be able to use session like this:

```
Context.Session.SetString("MyName", "Mike");
Context.Session.SetInt("MyAge", 21);
ViewBag.Name = Context.Session.GetString("MyName");
ViewBag.Age = Context.Session.GetInt("MyAge");
```

Comment: I tried adding the Microsoft.AspNet.Session dependency in my project.json file, but project.json didn't recognize that, and Context.Session.SetInt (etc.) still isn't recognized. Is there another dependency I could be missing?

Comment: Have you got `using Microsoft.AspNet.Http;` in your controller?

Comment: The using Microsoft.AspNet.Http fixed so I got the GetString(), SetString() methods. But my Session object is still not instanced. So I still get the InvalidException thrown when trying to access the object.

Comment: How are you trying to access your session object?

Answer (score 0):

In my case `HttpContext.Session.SetString()` only appeared after adding `using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;`. Initially I had only `using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;`. To recap...you need both of these using statements for Session.SetString() to be available in ASP.Net MVC Core 1.1:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
```

Answer (score -2):

Install "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Extensions" with NuGet to access SetString() and GetString() methods.