# Session Variables in ASP.NET Core 1.0

Tags: session, razor, session-variables, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm trying to do something simple in an ASP.NET Core 1.0 / ASP.net Core Mvc project: get and set simple session variables. But it has proven very difficult. I tried following the advice in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29432614/422845), which is to add the dependency -- "Microsoft.AspNet.Session": "1.0.0-beta3" -- to project.json, and then use Context.Session.SetInt("myVar", 35), but that did not work. The SetInt() method is still not recognized.

Do I need to include another dependency? What am I missing?

Comment: is there a particular reason you need session variables? Personally it was the first thing I used to turn off on the old templates, only turning them on when I had exhausted all other possible ways of not using them as sessions variables are a scalability and performance bottleneck.

Comment: I'm conditionally setting the Layout variable in _ViewStart.cshtml to allow our developers to set a "?dev=1" query string to develop in a new layout that we don't want to propagate globally yet. Right now that works and they can go to "some/page?dev=1" to see the page they're developing on in the new template. I want this choice to hold through the session, so they can navigate through the site and keep that new layout.

Comment: Have you added `using Microsoft.AspNet.Http;` to your controller file?

Comment: just tried myself and after adding the dependency on project json and the using as @MikeBrind suggested I have the session working ok.

Comment: I've blogged about how to use Session in ASP.NET5 if it helps: http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/270/sessions-in-asp-net-5

Comment: @MikeBrind - great article, very helpful! I did everything in the article, including adding the dependency to project.json, adding app.UseInMemorySession() to Startup.cs, and including using Microsoft.AspNet.Http. Now while I'm typing the code, the SetInt() and GetInt() methods are recognized properly. *But*, when I view the page, I'm getting the error "Session has not been configured for this application or request", and I'm not sure why. There shouldn't be a problem using the session in _ViewStart.cshtml, right?

Comment: I can't think of one good reason for setting or getting session variables in a ViewStart file. But the error you report sounds more like a bug to me.

Answer (score 1):

Try following this sample:
https://github.com/aspnet/Session/blob/dev/samples/SessionSample/Startup.cs

You will need to configure the session middleware first, then include the appropriate usings.

```
public class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddCaching();
        services.AddSession();
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
        app.UseSession(o => {
            o.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30); });
    }
}
```

The relevant usings are

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Http;
```