# Unable to use session in ASP.Net vNext Project

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, session

I have an ASP.Net vNext project that uses Session. But I am getting this error while trying to get/set values in the session.

> An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in Microsoft.AspNet.Http.Core.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Session has not been configured for this application or request.

Here's my controller method:

```
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [HttpGet("/admin")]
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        if (Context.Session.GetString("UserName") == null) // error thrown here
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Login");
        }

        return View();
    }
```

I have added the KVM package `"Microsoft.AspNet.Session": "1.0.0-beta3"` in my `project.json` file as well and have configured my application to use session via my `Startup.cs` like so:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // code removed for brevity
    services.AddCachingServices();
    services.AddSessionServices();
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
        app.UseMvc();
        app.UseInMemorySession(configure: s => s.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30));
    }
```

I have looked at the vNext documentation on Github but it does not provide much information about ASP.Net sessions. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

So I figured this out. The fix was quite simple actually. Since ASP.Net adds the middlewares sequentially into the request pipeline, all I needed to do was use the session middleware before using MVC. More info here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29569746/832546

**Fixed code:**

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
{
    app.UseInMemorySession(configure: s => s.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30));
    app.UseMvc();
}
```

Comment: Yes this was helpful. I just moved ```app.UseSession();``` before ```app.UseMvc();```

Answer (score 16):

Thanks to @acrhistof the link helped.

So if you are using RC1:
add this these dependencies in project.json:

```
 "Microsoft.AspNet.Session": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
 "Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory": "1.0.0",
```

in Startup.cs file:

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddCaching();
        services.AddSession();
        services.AddMvc();
    }
```

and

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
     app.UseSession(); //outside of dev  if (env.IsDevelopment())
     ....
     }
```

Comment: Use "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session": "1.0.0" if you are on ASP.net CORE

Answer (score 5):

It seems like things changed once again and the well-known ASP.NET session has to be configured differently in the rc1. (no `UseInMemorySession()` or other `AppBuilder` methods are related to `Session`, now it is added as a service).

In general `Session` has to be installed, configured, and then used. All these steps are quite new and somewhat unusual. Moreover, it depends on Cache:

> Session is built on top of `IDistributedCache`, so you must configure
>   this as well, otherwise you will receive an error.

The quotation above is from ASP.NET 5 docs. All you need to do is described here: https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/app-state.html#installing-and-configuring-session.