# Session has not been configured for this application or request error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I am very new to asp.net I recently I came across this exception:

> System.InvalidOperationException

The details of the exception says:

> Session has not been configured for this application or request.

Here is the code snippet where it happens:

```
[HttpPost]
        public object Post([FromBody]loginCredentials value)
        {
            if (value.username.Equals("Admin")
                &&
                value.password.Equals("admin"))
            {
                HttpContext.Session.Set("userLogin", System.Text.UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(value.username)); //This the line that throws the exception.
                return new
                {
                    account = new
                    {
                        email = value.username
                    }
                };
            }
            throw new UnauthorizedAccessException("invalid credentials");
        }
```

I have no idea why it's happening or what does this error actually mean. 
Can someone please explain what might be causing this?

Comment: Check the question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29801631/unable-to-use-session-in-asp-net-vnext-project

Comment: For ASP NET Core 3.1 see [link](https://www.yogihosting.com/aspnet-core-actions/#session)

Answer (score 149):

In your Startup.cs you might need to call

app.UseSession before app.UseMvc

```js
app.UseSession();  
app.UseMvc();
```

For this to work, you will also need to make sure the *Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session* nuget package is installed.

**Update**

You dont not need to use app.UseMvc(); in .NET Core 3.0 or higher

Comment: Yes, this was an accepted answer on a similar question.

Comment: This solved it for me, I had rearranged some code in Startup.cs and forgot that the thing was 'operation order sensitive'. I wish the error message from the compiler gave this little reminder.

Comment: services.AddSession();

Comment: There is a little more to it than that, specifically you need to add Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session NuGet package to your app first, then in the appropriate place (just above app.UseMvc() as shown above) you need to call app.UseSession()

Here is a pretty good article that lays this process out in detail as well as info on usage https://benjii.me/2016/07/using-sessions-and-httpcontext-in-aspnetcore-and-mvc-core/

Comment: @Keselme. Mark this like answer!

Comment: This no longer works in .NET Core 3.0, where you're not supposed to make use of app.UseMvc() anymore. I now get an error saying the session wasn't configured for this application or request. Not sure where to put it now?

Comment: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session this is the key, it works on 3.1 don't use app.UseMvc()

Comment: Thank you. In .NetCore 3.1 no need app.UseMvc();

Answer (score 34):

Following code worked out for me:

Configure Services :

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
          //In-Memory
          services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();
          services.AddSession(options => {
          options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1);
          });              
          // Add framework services.
          services.AddMvc();
     }
```

Configure the HTTP Request Pipeline:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, 
                      ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
    loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
    loggerFactory.AddDebug();
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
       app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
       app.UseBrowserLink();
    }
    else
    {
       app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
    }
    app.UseStaticFiles();
    app.UseSession();
    app.UseMvc(routes =>
    {
        routes.MapRoute(
           name: "default",
           template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
     });
 }
```

Comment: Worked for me in .net core application.

Comment: The `AddDistributedMemoryCahce` is very important. And the order of the `AddSession` and `UseSession` is important too. The options in the `AddSession` aren't needed to get this to work

Answer (score 30):

### For .NET 6:

Go to your `Program.cs` first (to add the code there)

I inserted this at the **last** part of the builder:

```cs
builder.Services.AddSession();
```

I added this after `app.UseAuthorization();`

```cs
app.UseSession();
```

#### Final Output:

[image]

**Note:** I don't know if this is really the "right lines" to place the code, but this is what worked for me. (I'm still a beginner in ASP.NET as well)

Comment: Looking at microsoft's learn page on UseSession, they specify that UseSession should be placed after UseAuthorization as well.

Comment: The information is helpful at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state

Answer (score 21):

I was getting the exact same error in my .NET Core 3.0 Razor Pages application. Since, I'm not using `app.UseMvc()` the proposed answer could not work for me.

So, for anyone landing here having the same problem in .NET Core 3.0, here's what I did inside `Configure` to get it to work:

```
app.UseSession(); // use this before .UseEndpoints
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints => { endpoints.MapRazorPages(); });
```

Comment: Thanks! Putting the session before the endpoints fixed it for me too.

Comment: Putting .UseSession() before .UseEndpoints() worked for me too. Thank you!

Comment: This absolutely did not work. It caused an error in the startup. 
CreateHostBuilder(args)Build().Run() <- unable to resolve service for .. IsssionStore while attempting to activate session middleware

Answer (score 5):

**for .net core 5**

Below lines should be added in startup.cs

```
        services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();

        services.AddSession(options =>
        {
            options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10);
            options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
            options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
        });
```

`app.UseSession();` should be added before

```
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
```

Below codes can be used for set the value and reading the value

```
this.httpContext.Session.SetString(SessionKeyClientId, clientID);
clientID = this.httpContext.Session.GetString(SessionKeyClientId);
```

Comment: MS Learn website shows `app.UseSession();` after UseAuthorization.  See [HERE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state?view=aspnetcore-6.0)

Answer (score 4):

If you use .NET 6 add these below into your `Program.cs` (may not work in older versions):

```
builder.Services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();

builder.Services.AddSession(options =>
{
    options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
    options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
    options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
});

app.UseSession();
```

Be sure if `builder` and `app` are already declared. If it is not, add these below before the ones I said before:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
var app = builder.Build();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you got this issue and your startup was correctly setup: This error appeared for me when I forgot to await and async method that used IHttpContextAccessor that was injected. By adding await to the call the issue was resolved.

Answer (score 1):

For Razor Pages ASP.NET Core application in .NET5 (needs testing on newer runtime) :

Inside Startup.cs:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
services.AddRazorPages();
services.AddSession(); //Add this line to register the session service
}


public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
if (env.IsDevelopment())
{app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();}
else
{app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");}
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseSession(); //Add this line to enable the session for the app
app.UseRouting();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>{endpoints.MapRazorPages();});
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -6):

```
HttpContext.Session.Add("name", "value");
```

OR

```
HttpContext.Session["username"]="Value";
```

Comment: This does not answer the OP's question at all. Furthermore the Add and brackets [] method does not exist anymore in .NET Core.