# Context keyword doesn't get recognized in ASP.net 5 MVC Controller for use with Sessions

Tags: session-variables, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am using ASP.net 5 Beta 8. I want to make use of Sessions however Context keyword is not being understood.

In my packages.json

```
"Microsoft.AspNet.Http": "1.0.0-beta8",
"Microsoft.AspNet.Session": "1.0.0-beta8",
```

In my ConfigureServices of Startup.cs

```
 // Add MVC services to the services container.
 services.AddMvc();

 //Session Support
 services.AddSession();
 services.AddCaching();
```

In Configure of Startup.cs

```
        //Session
        app.UseSession();

        // Add MVC to the request pipeline.
        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
      });
```

In HomeController.cs

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Session;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Http;


public IActionResult Index()
{
    Context.Session.SetString("MyString", "test");
    return View();
}
```

And the error I get is

> The name 'Context' does not exist in the current context

I also tried removing dnx core from project.json

```
"frameworks": {
   "dnx451": { }
 },
```

but it also doesn't work.

Take note: I have used the previous answers on stackoverflow to try resolve the issue and it hasn't worked. e.g. [Link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29420262/sessions-in-asp-net-5)

I also tried various blog posts on Sessions in ASP.NET 5 but I still get the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Made some renames on beta 8, here is a helpful [link](https://christopherhackett.co.uk/blog/2015/10/17/ASP.NET-5-MVC-6-renames-in-beta-8/)

```
Older                               Beta 8
Context                             HttpContext
Context.Session.Set(String, byte[]) HttpContext.Session.SetInt32(String, byte[])
```

Diagnostics
Error pages provided by diagnostics have better names to avoid confusion.

```
app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();

Older                  Beta 8
app.ErrorHandler()     app.UseExceptionHandler()
app.ErrorPage()        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage()
```

Comment: Please do not just post links as an answer, as they might get deleted.

Answer (score 1):

Solution is to use HttpContext

```
 HttpContext.Session.SetString("MyString", "test");
```

Comment: ASP.NET 5 BETA 8 has renamed the Context to HTTPContext in the controller so it was just a simple rename