# How to get a session value in layout file in ASP.NET 5 MVC6

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

In ASP.NET 5 MVC 6 Beta 8 I need to read a session variable in in my `_Layout.cshtml` or alternatively get a reference to the current  HttpContext.

Take note: In ASP.NET 5 referencing the Session object has changed significantly from ASP.net 4 as detailed in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33210026/context-keyword-doesnt-get-recognized-in-asp-net-5-mvc-controller-for-use-with) question

The `Context` object has also been renamed to `HttpContext` between Beta7 and Beta8.

In My current controller I currently save the session variable like this

```
public IActionResult Index()
{
    HttpContext.Session.SetInt32("Template", (id));
}
```

In my _Layout.cshtml I need to read the above session variable.
I need to reference the current HttpContext somehow e.g

```
HttpContext.Current.Session.GetInt32("Template");
```

but I don't know how to the get the current HttpContext in a cshtml file.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The naming between `Context` and `HttpContext` is somewhat confusing. You can access the HttpContext in a view using the `Context` property:

```
@{ int x = Context.Session.GetInt32("test"); }
```

There is also a pending issue at the MVC repo regarding this: https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/3332

Comment: Thank you for the correct answer and GitHub link. What caught me out was that in the controller it is called HttpContext but in the View it is only Context.

Comment: Yeah, in beta8 they renamed it to `HttpContext` in the controller but they 'forgot' about the view.

Answer (score 5):

using razor, you can get values this way

```
@{
var sessionName = new Byte[20];
bool nameOK = Context.Session.TryGetValue("name", out sessionName);

if (nameOK)
{
    string result = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(sessionName);
    <p> @result</p>

}
}
```

change

```
string result = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(sessionName);
```

to

```
int intSessionValue = Int32.Parse(sessionName);
```

or to be safer

```
int intSessionValue = 0;
bool isConvertOK = Int32.TryParse(TextBoxD1.Text, out intSessionValue);
```

So you can check if conversion was successful

```
if (isConvertOK){
   //successful conversion from string to int
}
```