# Read Integer session value in layout file

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

in `_Layout` file, I need to read an int variable data from session.
I can read string very easily but an integer is very difficult.

I used this code for string:

```
var sessionImg = new Byte[20];
bool imageStatus = Context.Session.TryGetValue("_Image", out sessionImg);

if (imageStatus)
{
    string result = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(sessionImg); 
}
```

And for integer i convert Byte to string than string to Int.

```
var ByteClientID = new Byte[20];
bool IdStatus = Context.Session.TryGetValue("_ClientID", out ByteClientID);

if (IdStatus)
{
    string result1 = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ByteClientID);

    int intSessionValue = 0;
    bool isConvertOK = Int32.TryParse(result1, out intSessionValue);

    if (isConvertOK)
    {
    ........
    }
}
```

It is working but i didn't like this code. It doesn't look correct. 
`Context.Session.TryGetValue` only returns Byte..
Can anyone help me with this please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few [extension methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.sessionextensions?view=aspnetcore-2.2) on `ISession` in the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http` namespace. So just include that namespace, and then you can just use methods the methods [`GetInt32`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.sessionextensions.getint32?view=aspnetcore-2.2) and [`GetString`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.sessionextensions.getstring?view=aspnetcore-2.2) directly.

That saves you from reading the session data as bytes and converting that into a string first:

```
// using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;

string sessionImg = Context.Session.GetString("_Image");

int clientId = Context.Session.GetInt32("_ClientID");
```

To import the namespace within a Razor view, you can use the `@using` directive:

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;

<p>Image value: @Context.Session.GetString("_Image")</p>
<p>Client id: @Context.Session.GetInt32("_ClientID")</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

see this link: [How to get a session value in layout file in ASP.NET 5 MVC6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33212908/how-to-get-a-session-value-in-layout-file-in-asp-net-5-mvc6)

**Answer says:** The naming between Context and HttpContext is somewhat confusing. You can access the HttpContext in a view using the Context property:

```
@{ int x = Context.Session.GetInt32("test"); }
```

Comment: Thank you Imk. I tired this but it is not working.  'ISession' does not contain a definition for 'GetInt32' and no accessible extension method 'GetInt32' accepting a first argument of type 'ISession' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)